# ansible freeipa atomic - how to deploy image with atomic modules via ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, freeipa

there are those ansible modules for atomic:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/atomic_image_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/atomic_container_module.html

i want to wrap this command in ansible:

```
atomic install --name freeipa freeipa/freeipa-server --hostname=freeipa71.test.lx.domain.com ip-address 10.20.203.87 publish ipa-server-install --setup-dns --forwarder=10.10.30.1 --admin-password=adminadmin --ds-password=adminadmin --realm=LX.DOMAIN.COM --domain=lx.domain.com --auto-reverse --unattended
```

is this even possible with one of those modules? i hadn't found a working way till yet, i'm trying like but thats not working:

```
- atomic_container:
    name: freeipa
    image: freeipa/freeipa-server
    backend: ostree
    state: latest
    mode: system
    values:
        - hostname=freeipa71.lx.domain.com
        - publish
        - ipa-server-install
        - --setup-dns
        - -forwarder=10.10.30.1 
        - --admin-password=adminadmin 
        - --ds-password=adminadmin 
        - --realm=LX.DOMAIN.COM 
        - --domain=lx.domain.com 
        - --auto-reverse 
        - --unattended
```

edit:
error output is:

```
fatal: [freeipa71.lx.domain.com]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "backend": "ostree",
            "image": "docker.io/freeipa/freeipa-server",
            "mode": "system",
            "name": "freeipa",
            "rootfs": null,
            "state": "latest",
            "values": [
                "hostname=freeipa71.lx.domain.com",
                "ip-address=10.203.0.12",
                "publish",
                "ipa-server-install",
                "--setup-dns",
                "--forwarder=10.10.30.1",
                "--admin-password=adminadmin",
                "--ds-password=adminadmin",
                "--realm=LX.DOMAIN.COM",
                "--domain=lx.domain.com",
                "--auto-reverse",
                "--unattended"
            ]
        }
    },
    "msg": "Invalid value 'publish'.  Expected form NAME=VALUE\n",
    "rc": 1
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
freeipa71.lx.domain.com     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: Run it with `-vvv` and post the error.

Comment: did, i'm sorry for not posting the error from the beginning

Comment: The error is clear `"msg": "Invalid value 'publish'.  Expected form NAME=VALUE"` . There is nothing Ansible can do for you until you fix the `Values for the installation of the container.`

Comment: yeah the error is clear; but in my opinion the module is lacking support for

1. take arguments before the run command (--hostname=freeipa71.test.lx.domain.com ip-address 10.20.203.87 publish)
2. take an docker run override (ipa-server-install)
3. specify arguments without a value (--setup-dns --auto-reverse --unattended)

Comment: what i actually want to know is if the ansible module can build an atomic command like i posted or if this is not possible

Comment: If "`the module is lacking support for ...`" *atomic issue* at [github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+atomic) might be the right place.